# How to divide page in two column FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to divide page in to two column using FPDF. I am using below code which created pdf in two cloumn but issue is that the gap is some bit more between column. I want to reduce gap between the column only.

My code here

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
protected $col = 0; // Current column
protected $y0;      // Ordinate of column start

function Header()
{
}

function Footer()
{
}

function SetCol($col)
{
    // Set position at a given column
    $this->col = $col;
    $x = 10+$col*50;
    $this->SetLeftMargin($x);
    $this->SetX($x);
}

function AcceptPageBreak()
{
    if($this->col<2)
    {
        // Go to next column
        $this->SetCol($this->col+2);
        // Set ordinate to top
        $this->SetY($this->y0);
        // Keep on page
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Go back to first column
        $this->SetCol(0);
        // Page break
        return true;
    }
}

function ChapterBody($file)
{
    $txt = file_get_contents($file);
    $this->SetFont('Times','',12);
    $this->MultiCell(100, 7, $txt);

    $this->Ln();
    $this->SetCol(0);
}

function PrintChapter($num, $title, $file)
{
    // Add chapter
    $this->AddPage();
    $this->ChapterBody($file);
}
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$title = '20000 Leagues Under the Seas';
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Jules Verne');
$pdf->PrintChapter(1,'A RUNAWAY REEF','20k_c1.txt');
$pdf->Output();
```

In the below image you can see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are skipping to third column. See bellow with two columns per page:

```
function AcceptPageBreak()
{
    if($this->col<1)
    {
        // Go to next column
        $this->SetCol($this->col+1);
        // Set ordinate to top
        $this->SetY($this->y0);
        // Keep on page
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Go back to first column
        $this->SetCol(0);
        // Page break
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @blueCat. I not just want to skip third column. Your code just remove third column. but space of third column is remaining.  I want to divide the third column space between the remaining two column.

Comment: If you run my version it gave the same result ?

Comment: Man i have already did but your script just remove third cloumn

Comment: `$x = 10+$col*40;` ?